# Javafx mysql, how to get rows one by one

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, resultset

So i'm working on flashcards app and got stuck. I need textfield that get word from my DB, shows it on the screen and change to the next one after user press button. Problem is that when i'm using resultset to set textfield it shows only the last row from DB. I've got no idea how to get first value from DB and then change it to the next after user pres button.

That's part of my button controller:

```
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT fiszka_eng FROM "+LoginHandler.GetLogin()+"");
        while(res.next())
        {
            String textENG = res.getString("table");
            TextField.setText(textENG);
        //Here i want to wait till the button is pressed and after - change textENG to next row
        }
```

Comment: Java supports MySQL prepared statements i suggest using them to prevent SQL injections..

Comment: You should store the result set into another list . Then do iteration from list. Otherwise database connection won't close.

Comment: Here is a way the structure the application:
(1) First, read the database and query all the flashcard data - iterate the result set and populate into a `List<Flashcard>` (create a `Flashcard` class and have the list with all the Flashcards).
(2) Next, in the GUI when the user presses a button - get the first flash card from the `List<Flashcard>` and display in the GUI's text field. Then on the next button press get the next card from the list and display, etc. until all the cards are over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you iterate over whole `ResultSet` object thus setting `textENG` to last value from db. Maybe add `textENG` to `List` and then on button click show next element of that list.